# Angular 2-4 accordion style nav

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am having issues with my accordion style mobile nav bar showing content underneath the specific tab.  I am using  to grab the content from a component and pull in the view but it shows the data underneath the nav bar and not under the specific div. Any ideas would be helpful! thanks.

**Code for NavBar**

```
`<div class="container panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <nav style="padding-top: 50px;">
      <ul class="nav nav-justified">
        <li routerLinkActive="active current"><a routerLink="/all">All</a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active current"><a routerLink="/1">1</a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active current"><a routerLink="/2">2</a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active current"><a routerLink="/3">3</a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active current"><a routerLink="/4">4</a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active current"><a routerLink="/5">5</a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active current"><a routerLink="/6">6</a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active current"><a routerLink="/7">7</a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active current"><a routerLink="/8">8</a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active current"><a routerLink="/9">9</a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active current"><a routerLink="/notifications">Notifications</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
</div>`
```

**Code for all-apps.html**

```
`<div class="container">
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
  <div class="panel-body">`
```

**All-Apps component.ts**

```
`import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-apps',
  templateUrl: './all-apps.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-apps.component.css']
})
export class AllAppsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
blah
}
`
```

[Nav Bar View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GR9GO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hi firstly don't use `routerLink="/all"` and `routerLinkActive="active current"` in the different tags

use `<a routerLink="/all" routerLinkActive="active">text</a>` this is the proper way of using it.